# How to access the maximum value for a given attribute in d3 tree layout

Tags: d3.js, svg

For instance I would like to size nodes according to the size attribute like this,

```
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d){return d.size;});
```

This works fine but attempting to normalize this so that it does not exceed some value e.g. When attempting to make the radius not exceed 1, I tried

```
node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", d.size/(d3.max(function(d){return d.size;}) - d3.min(function(d){return d.size;})));
```

However, this is not returning anything

Comment: Show some effort and you might find someone willing to help.

Comment: you are not returning value in second one. write function and return value